# Write xml file to TextArea instead of a file

Tags: php

I have a `TextArea` called `myTextArea` and I want to write xml into it instead of the file. How can I do this?

my current code:

```
$doc->formatOutput = true; 

$r = $doc->createElement( "employees" ); 
$doc->appendChild( $r ); 
foreach( $employees as $employee ) 
{ 
    $b = $doc->createElement( "employee" ); 
    $name = $doc->createElement( "name" ); 
    $name->appendChild( 
        $doc->createTextNode( $employee['name'] ) 
    ); 
    $b->appendChild( $name ); 

    $age = $doc->createElement( "age" ); 
    $age->appendChild( 
        $doc->createTextNode( $employee['age'] ) 
    ); 
    $b->appendChild( $age ); 

    $salary = $doc->createElement( "salary" ); 
    $salary->appendChild( 
        $doc->createTextNode( $employee['salary'] ) 
    ); 
    $b->appendChild( $salary ); 
    $r->appendChild( $b ); 
} 

echo $doc->saveXML(); 
$doc->save("write.xml");

?> 
<Form name="fName">
<TextArea name="myTextArea"></TextArea>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the textarea tags add something like:

```
<?php echo $doc->saveXML(); ?>
```